# XCODE Error : "...the field reciever doesn't exist in your schema (Code: 102, Version: 1.7.5)."

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm getting this error now in my build in XCode.

```
2015-07-14 23:42:37.819 Parlay[1010:110971] [Error]: The field reciever doesn't exist in your schema (Code: 102, Version: 1.7.5)
```

What is this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Parse SDK, so the column you are requesting in your table does not exist or is wrongly typed.

You might need to check that the key in your app is the same as in the table in Parse.

I had the same error here :
[query whereKey:@"reciever" equalTo:...];

Comment: OHHHHH ok. I will check out my queries now! Thanks!